# WildFly - EJB invocations from a remote client - Operation failed with status WAITING

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.1, wildfly, wildfly-8

Following is my code to invoke an ejb, but it wait for the connection and get failed. I changed the port to 4447 but no luck.

```
private DataGridService lookupRemoteEJB() throws NamingException {

    Context context = null;
    try {

        Properties clientProperties = new Properties();
        clientProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connections", "default");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "4447");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.host", "127.0.0.1");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "admin");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "password");
        clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");

        EJBClientConfiguration ejbClientConfiguration = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(clientProperties);
        ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> contextSelector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(ejbClientConfiguration);
        EJBClientContext.setSelector(contextSelector);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        context = new InitialContext(properties);

        String jndiName = "ejb:poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0//DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService";
        System.out.println("____" + jndiName);

        return (DataGridService) context.lookup(jndiName);

    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

JNDI in server console for the stateless session bean.

```
11:00:53,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean name
d DataGridServiceImpl in deployment unit subdeployment "poc_ejbs-1.0.jar" of deployment "poc_ear-1.0.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0/DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService
        java:app/poc_ejbs-1.0/DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService
        java:module/DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService
        java:jboss/exported/poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0/DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService
        java:global/poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0/DataGridServiceImpl
        java:app/poc_ejbs-1.0/DataGridServiceImpl
        java:module/DataGridServiceImpl

11:00:53,284 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HQ221007: Server is now live
11:00:53,285 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.1.Final (Fast Hornet, 124) [73e4f957-b7a5-11
```

Error Trace:

```
____ejb:poc_ear-1.0/poc_ejbs-1.0//DataGridServiceImpl!com.oms.ejbs.DataGridService
Feb 19, 2015 10:48:33 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.0.1.Final
Feb 19, 2015 10:48:34 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 19, 2015 10:48:36 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 19, 2015 10:48:38 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
Feb 19, 2015 10:48:44 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 127.0.0.1:1099
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:94)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:155)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:115)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:271)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getData(Unknown Source)
    at com.oms.client.EJBInvoker.main(EJBInvoker.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line solved my problem, port has to be changed to `8080`

```
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, http port did not help me.
I could do it with remote port.

I have added:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
        ...
        <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
```

And added port:

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
            ...
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

EDIT: local I can only connect with remote 4447 and with webstart (jnlp) only with http port...