# Run Java RMI between 2 docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, wildfly, rmi

i'am trying to run java RMI between 2 docker container(using docker-compose).
On each container there is javaEE application(EAR file)  running on wildfly 8.2

To be honnest  I'am not sure 100% that Docker allow me to do such thing (RMI), so is it possible? if it's the case is there any special configuration to follow? 
I'am ready to provide all details of my work in order to get your help.

Comment: seems to be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759967/java-rmi-server-in-docker-container but with 2 containers instead of one.

Comment: i don't think so , it's not the same message , in my case i have this message: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 172.19.0.3:4747

Comment: Not familiar with wildfly. Did you try changing your port to 8080 as per this discussion on your EJB error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599179/wildfly-ejb-invocations-from-a-remote-client-operation-failed-with-status-wa

Comment: the 2 containers can ping on each other..also i checked the ports with nc command the RMI ports are open on both sides.....

Comment: I'm looking at details in standalone.xml or ejb-client.xml or maybe it's a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue thanks to wildfly since the remote call is over http so all i have to do is to expose ports from both sides ( 2 containers ) and configure standalone.xml like usual.